# Soundtrack recomendation

Tags: audio

I'm building a 1 min tv-ad for a college assignment and I'm looking for a "crescendo" music... something like

but not as easily recognized because I don't want to people focusing on "where have i heard that before?!?"...

Extra info: The plot for the video is a craftsman that walks into a dark room, turn the lights on, removes a sheet from his tools, and crafts a... ... ... guess what?!? piece of crap chair ("anti-climax") that falls apart by itself, and i fade to a "don't stop practicing, Bla classes for only 19,99"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty funny idea! If you have $50 to spend, you can get royalty-free music from audiomicro.com. Incompetech.com also has royalty-free music; I don't know how much it costs.  And if you use iMovie (which comes free with every Mac), their FREE audio library might include something you could use.  You could even splice together several songs into one to get the effect you want.